# Moving a vector according to its X Rotation

Tags: java

I have this code to move the position vector according to it't Y Rotation but I can't find anything on moving the bullet in this case move up or down according to it's X Rotation.

```
position.x += (float)((SPEED * DisplayManager.getDelta()) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(-getRotY() + 90)));
position.z += (float)((SPEED * DisplayManager.getDelta()) * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(-getRotY() + 90)));
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean like this?

```
position.y += (float)((SPEED * DisplayManager.getDelta()) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(-getRotX() + 90)));
position.z += (float)((SPEED * DisplayManager.getDelta()) * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(-getRotX() + 90)));
```

Comment: No those two lines of code make the vector (the bullet) move forward in the direction (rotation x). What I was asking was how I would make it move up or down according to its rotation y.